# How do I make a nested list in Dokka?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-dokka, kdoc

Trying to document some Kotlin code with a pretty routine structure:

1. A numbered list.

   - With a bulleted sublist.
2. Where the numbers continue correctly at the top level of the list.

What I take to be the [official Dokka page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html) doesn't even have the word "list" on the page. Have Googled hither and yon without finding any info on how to do this. Help!

Answer (score 9):

As far as I can see, nesting with additional indentation of four spaces works:

```
/**
 * 1. A numbered list.
 *     * With a bulleted sublist.
 * 1. Where the numbers continue correctly at the top level of the list.
 */
val foo: Int = 0
```

The result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Dokka uses markdown, which has some forks and flavors and not standardized at all, but this works:

```
/**
 * list:
 * - item1
 * - item2
 *
 * numbered:
 * 1. one
 * 2. two
 */
```

[image: this is what it will look like]

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but based on https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/blob/c2afb34/core/src/main/kotlin/Markdown/MarkdownProcessor.kt#L52 it looks like Dokka defaults to CommonMark.